# Golang: healthd and healthtop of the library "gocraft/health"

Tags: go, metrics, pack

Im using **gocraft/health** to check the health of my service and have the metrics of each endPoint. 
Im usin The JSON polling sink to get the metrics.

```
sink := health.NewJsonPollingSink(time.Minute*5, time.Minute*5)
stream.AddSink(sink)
```

I want to use  **healthtop and healthd**  here [Link](https://github.com/gocraft/health#healthd-and-healthtop)  they explain how.

I fixed the environment variables: `export HEALTHD_MONITORED_HOSTPORTS=:5001 HEALTHD_SERVER_HOSTPORT=:5002 healthd`
 as they said

after they said "Now you can run it". how, they didn't give any command to do it.I didn't realy understand what they mean.

I navigated to **src/github.com/gocraft/health/cmd/healthd**. I found **main.go** when I run it I got that in the console

```
    [openrtb@sd-69536 healthd]$ go run main.go
    [2015-06-17T23:04:20.871743758Z]: job:general event:starting kvs:[health_host_port::5002 monitored_host_ports::5001,:5002 server_host_port::5002]
    [2015-06-17T23:04:20.87810814Z]: job:poll status:success time:4 ms kvs:[host_port::5002]
    [2015-06-17T23:04:20.881896459Z]: job:poll status:success time:8 ms kvs:[host_port::5001]
    [2015-06-17T23:04:20.882338024Z]: job:recalculate status:success time:231 μs
    [2015-06-17T23:04:23.275370787Z]: job:recalculate status:success time:6 μs
    [2015-06-17T23:04:30.875230839Z]: job:poll status:success time:1573 μs kvs:[host_port::5002]
    [2015-06-17T23:04:30.881415193Z]: job:poll status:success time:7 ms kvs:[host_port::5001]
.
.
```

but no reslute on the those endpoints

**localhost:5002/jobs: Lists top jobs**

**localhost:5002/hosts: Lists all monitored hosts and their statuses**

it gave me **{"error": "not_found"}**

excepte this **localhost:5002/health** I got this JSON responce

```
{
    "instance_id": "sd-69536.1291",
    "interval_duration": 3600000000000,
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "interval_start": "2015-06-18T01:00:00+02:00",
            "serial_number": 48,
            "jobs": {
                "general": {
                    "timers": {},
                    "events": {
                        "starting": 1
                    },
                    "event_errs": {},
                    "count": 0,
                    "nanos_sum": 0,
                    "nanos_sum_squares": 0,
                    "nanos_min": 0,
                    "nanos_max": 0,
                    "count_success": 0,
                    "count_validation_error": 0,
                    "count_panic": 0,
                    "count_error": 0,
                    "count_junk": 0
                },
                "poll": {
                    "timers": {},
                    "events": {},
                    "event_errs": {},
                    "count": 24,
                    "nanos_sum": 107049159,
                    "nanos_sum_squares": 6.06770682813009e+14,
                    "nanos_min": 1581783,
                    "nanos_max": 8259442,
                    "count_success": 24,
                    "count_validation_error": 0,
                    "count_panic": 0,
                    "count_error": 0,
                    "count_junk": 0
                },
                "recalculate": {
                    "timers": {},
                    "events": {},
                    "event_errs": {},
                    "count": 23,
                    "nanos_sum": 3501601,
                    "nanos_sum_squares": 6.75958305123e+11,
                    "nanos_min": 70639,
                    "nanos_max": 290877,
                    "count_success": 23,
                    "count_validation_error": 0,
                    "count_panic": 0,
                    "count_error": 0,
                    "count_junk": 0
                }
            },
            "timers": {},
            "events": {
                "starting": 1
            },
            "event_errs": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

but no idea what this result mean, because it doesn't have any relation with my
**localhost:5001/health** EndPoint that should normaly aggregate as they said.

Comment: late to the party, but healthd's endpoints are e.g. http://localhost:5002/healthd/jobs or /healthd/aggregations (based on `HEALTHD_SERVER_HOSTPORT=:5002`)

Answer (score 1):

What you downloaded is a binary so you can just invoke it with `healthd` if you're in the correct directory, they actually provide this example;

```
HEALTHD_MONITORED_HOSTPORTS=:5020 HEALTHD_SERVER_HOSTPORT=:5032 healthd
```

Which isn't setting env var as much as invoking healthd with those two values (export or something would be required to persist the change beyond the one command). healthtop more clearly states what it is but as you can see by their paths, they're both commands `gocraft/health/cmd/healthtop`. They have several examples of using healthtop from bash, not so explicit about healthd but it's the same.

If you ran that command (as you show in your question) then you may want to try `healthtop jobs` or something to that effect. I don't know a ton about this project and don't care to research it but from what I can tell `healthd` is just a service that collects results from various `/health` endpoints and makes them available in on API. It seems like they intend for you to use `healthtop` to on top of it to view reports.

Also note this;

> Great! To get a sense of the type of data healthd serves, you can manually navigate to:
>   /jobs: Lists top jobs
>   /aggregations: Provides a time series of aggregations
>   /aggregations/overall: Squishes all time series aggregations into one aggregation.
>   /hosts: Lists all monitored hosts and their statuses.
>   However, viewing raw JSON is just to give you a sense of the data. See the next section...

I'm not sure what the domain is (localhost:5032 if you're running locally?) but you should probably just be able to go to localhost:5032/jobs and see the `healthd` is running and doing something. Also check your apps to confirm it's up and running. Don't expect any output from it directly, that's what `healthtop` is for.

Comment: BTW, doing `VAR=val VAR2=val2 command` is a sh/bash-ism that will not work in other environments/shells. The generic way to do this on is via `env`, that is: `env VAR=val VAR2=val2 command`. That will (should) work on all POSIX systems.

Comment: you said "I can just invoke it with healthd if you're in the correct directory", which directory.

Comment: @DaveC  that's what I did `export HEALTHD_MONITORED_HOSTPORTS=:5001 HEALTHD_SERVER_HOSTPORT=:5002 healthd
`

Comment: @Azis `export` does not equal `env`. Export (again shell specific, but I'll assume sh or bash) only marks some variables as exported (visible to later commands), possibly setting them. It's used like `export VAR=val VAR2=val2 VAR3 VAR4`, note there is no command, you cannot tack `healthd` on the end!! On the other hand, `env` is a shell-independent tool which sets/changes some values, and then runs a command (whatever is on the command line after the last `X=y` is a command and it's arguments).

Comment: @Aziz when I said correct directory I meant the one which contains `healthd`. Alternatively your path could include the directly `healthd` is in which would make it accessible anyway. Anyway, it looks like you got healthd running now. I would try the other service. It's supposed to give you a better view of the data.

Comment: I got running but no answer from **localhost:5002/jobs** or the other endPoint